# Float into uint8_t array

Tags: c

I want to make 4 different ADC measurements. I want to be that those readed values are floats. After that I want to put those 4 float values in an uint8_t to send it over the function:

```
uint32_t ble_nus_data_send(ble_nus_t * p_nus,
                           uint8_t   * p_data,
                           uint16_t  * p_length,
                           uint16_t    conn_handle)
```

This minimal code works:

```
static void app_timer_handler(void * p_context)
{
  uint8_t p_dat[] = "hi";
  uint16_t len = sizeof(p_dat)-1;

  ret_code_t err_code = ble_nus_data_send(&m_nus, p_dat, &len, m_conn_handle);
  APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
}
```

But when I try to send a val it goes wrong:

```
static void app_timer_handler(void * p_context)
{
  if(m_conn_handle != BLE_CONN_HANDLE_INVALID)
  {
    uint8_t values[20];

    ret_code_t err_code;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(0, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    float value1 = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    sprintf((char*)values, "%.2f", value1);
    uint16_t len = sizeof(values);

    err_code = ble_nus_data_send(&m_nus, values, &len, m_conn_handle); 
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
  }
}
```

After getting the sample value of the ADC I will make calculations to get the voltage. I read it out with a 12-bit adc.

The expected received output of the uint8_t must be like [float1 float2 float3 float4]. This because I want to process the values in Python and plot them in a graph.

To receive the sended data I do use a dongle.

I did try this:

```
static void app_timer_handler(void * p_context)
{
  if(m_conn_handle != BLE_CONN_HANDLE_INVALID)
  {
    float values[4];

    ret_code_t err_code;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(0, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    values[0] = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(1, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    values[1] = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(2, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    values[2] = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(3, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    values[3] = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    uint16_t len = sizeof(values);

    err_code = ble_nus_data_send(&m_nus, (uint8_t*)values, &len, m_conn_handle); 
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
  }
}
```

[Received values1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJVKN.png)

And also tried this:

```
static void app_timer_handler(void * p_context)
{
  if(m_conn_handle != BLE_CONN_HANDLE_INVALID)
  {
    uint8_t values[4];

    ret_code_t err_code;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(0, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    float value1 = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(1, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    float value2 = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(2, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    float value3 = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    err_code = nrfx_saadc_sample_convert(3, &m_sample);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
    float value4 = m_sample * 3.0 / 4096;

    sprintf(values, "%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", value1, value2, value3, value4);
    uint16_t len = sizeof(values);

    err_code = ble_nus_data_send(&m_nus, (uint8_t*)values, &len, m_conn_handle); 
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
  }
}
```

[Received values2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jUkY.png)

Both ways didn't worked out for the output.

The output expected on Python is [val1 val2 val3 val4]. So the values can be seperated.

This is the function that handles the received data on the dongle.

```
static void ble_nus_chars_received_uart_print(uint8_t * p_data, uint16_t data_len)
{
    bsp_board_led_invert(LED_BLE_NUS_RX);
    NRF_LOG_DEBUG("Received data from BLE NUS. Writing data on CDC ACM.");
    NRF_LOG_HEXDUMP_DEBUG(p_data, data_len);
    memcpy(m_nus_data_array, p_data, data_len);

    // Add endline characters
    uint16_t length = data_len;
    if (length + sizeof(ENDLINE_STRING) < BLE_NUS_MAX_DATA_LEN)
    {
        memcpy(m_nus_data_array + length, ENDLINE_STRING, sizeof(ENDLINE_STRING));
        length += sizeof(ENDLINE_STRING);
    }

    // Send data through CDC ACM
    ret_code_t ret = app_usbd_cdc_acm_write(&m_app_cdc_acm,
                                            m_nus_data_array,
                                            length);
    if(ret != NRF_SUCCESS)
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("CDC ACM unavailable, data received: %s", m_nus_data_array);
    }
}
```

The received values are random chars. I think this might be because the receiving function. Do I have to make changes there or somewhere else?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain **why** you need to pass float values as an array of `uint8_t`? What do you want to achieve? What is function `ble_nus_data_send` supposed to do with the data? Based on the function name: Where does it send the data? What will the receiving side do with the data? Do you want to pass the internal binary representation of the `float` values? Or a text representation of the values? Note that calculations like `float value1 = sample * 3.0 / 4096;` use `double` and the result will be converted to `float`. Use `3.0f` if you want to use `float` calculation.

Comment: Your code will probably result in compilation errors. Please make sure you copy&paste exactly the code that you compiled and ran on your system. You mix variable names like `value1` and `val1`. The last `sprintf` will overwrite `data_array`, so all previous `sprintf`/`memcpy` are useless.

Comment: Yes I did make an update with the answer below.

Comment: You still did not provide enough background information about what will happen with the data. The image shows that you used PuTTY to display the data received on a serial port. To see useful data in a terminal program like PuTTY, you would have to send a text representation of the data as the last `sprintf` in your code would do. Function `ble_nus_chars_received_uart_print` seems to pass the data, so it does not clarify what format of the data is needed. BTW: `memcpy(m_nus_data_array, p_data, data_len);` might write past the end of the buffer if `data_len` is too large.

Comment: I want to put the received values on the serial port. So after that I can plot the values with Pyhton. So I need a array of the 4 float values on UART to work with it on Python. Makes this it clear? Sorry if I'm not clear enough. I'm at a very young stage.

Comment: *Please [edit] your question and add all requirements to the question.* To read the data with Python in a portable way it is probably best to define a text format and parse this text in your Python script. If you always have 4 values, I suggest to create a text representation with 4 values in one terminated line like `sprintf(data_array, "%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", val0, val1, val2, val3);` (Note the `\n`.) Showing the Python code would help to understand what format the data needs to be.

Comment: Isn't that making it complicated, because then I have to make it again an float from a string in Python?

Comment: I did make another edit I hope this will make it more understandable to help me out.

Comment: Converting float to text and back might be a bit slower but it would be portable. The systems that send and receive the data may have different endianness and even different floating point representation. It is difficult to guess why you see wrong data because there are unknown functions involved. Did you check if the baud rate setting is correct? I suggest to create a [mre]. Start with sending a hard coded string to the serial port. Then add `sprintf` to format float values, then add more complicated parts...

Comment: Yes I did already send a hard coded string and it worked fine. Only when I try to send the values it goes wrong.

Comment: Show both versions with hard coded string and float values.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I reverted the changes again. The purpose of this site is not only to answer a question for you personally, but also as a reference for others that might have a similar problem. We donated our time to write answers, and the answers would become useless when the question would be changed to something different. If you have a related question, write a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the float array as raw data, ie, the bytes they already are:

```
float values[4];

values[0] = sample * ...
values[1] = sample * ...
values[2] = sample * ...
values[3] = sample * ...

uint16_t d_len = sizeof(values);

err_code = ble_nus_data_send(&m_nus, (uint8_t *)values, &d_len, m_conn_handle); 
APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
```

Note that a typical size of float is 4 bytes.
Also, sending raw float values will work fine if the receiver is using the SAME floating point representation.

Here's a suggestion for the receiving side, just to verify your float values are being received properly:

```
static void ble_nus_chars_received_uart_print(uint8_t * p_data, uint16_t data_len)
{
    float *myFloats = (float *)p_data;
    bsp_board_led_invert(LED_BLE_NUS_RX);
    NRF_LOG_HEXDUMP_DEBUG(p_data, data_len);

    NRF_LOG_INFO("Float value 0: %f", myFloats[0]);
    NRF_LOG_INFO("Float value 1: %f", myFloats[1]);
    NRF_LOG_INFO("Float value 2: %f", myFloats[2]);
    NRF_LOG_INFO("Float value 3: %f", myFloats[3]);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a problem, because the function data_send( ) expects uint8_t for values.

Comment: sorry, added a cast: `(uint8_t *)values`

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I think it worked but I'm getting random chars on the receiver side. I think there must be some changes there also.

Comment: @user20656617 well, four floats are sent, so the receiving buffer could similarly be an array of four floats.

Comment: Don't know if I did it right, because I'm new on this. But I tried to add an image of the UART print of the receiving dongle.

Comment: Seems you're trying to edit my answer.  Add the image to your original question instead : )

Comment: Yes, I thougt that will work :( I added the picture in the original question. So you can get a better view.

Comment: I did add the receiving part function in my original question. Can this cause the random values?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution but shows errors in your code and a possible fix.

```
    uint8_t values[4];
```

This is an array of 4 bytes. It can hold a string of 3 characters and a terminating NUL (`'\0'`) character.

```
    sprintf(values, "%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", value1, value2, value3, value4);
```

This will write many more characters, so it will write past the end of the array which is undefined behavior.

```
    uint16_t len = sizeof(values);
```

This is the size of the array which is 4. You probably need the number of characters which would be the return value from `sprintf` or could be obtained with `strlen`.

Incomplete and untested example:

```
    /* I did not check the maximum size for the format string.
     * Can probably be smaller. */
    uint8_t values[100];

/* ... */

    /* In contrast to sprintf, snprintf limits the number of characters including
     * the terminating '\0' to the specified size. Might not be necessary if you
     * correctly calculate the maximum possible string length and define the 
     * array size accordingly. */
    int bytes = snprintf(values, sizeof(values),
                         "%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", value1, value2, value3, value4);

    if(bytes < 0)
    {
        /* error occurred */
        bytes = 0;
    }
    else if(bytes >= sizeof(values))
    {
       /* output was truncated */
       bytes = sizeof(values) - 1;
    }
    uint16_t len = bytes;

    err_code = ble_nus_data_send(&m_nus, (uint8_t*)values, &len, m_conn_handle);
```

Comment: Thanks Bodo! I tried it but I'm getting empty receivings. If I put chars between the " " I do get them but the other places are empty. I think something goes wrong with the ADC values.

Comment: @user20656617 I suggest to run the code in a debugger and check what's going on. Floating point values cannot be empty, so there must be something wrong. Read the documentation of your development environment. Maybe there are restrictions, e.g. `*printf` does not support floats?

Comment: Hi Bodo, I did run the code in the debugger. If I watch the m_sample the value of it changes. What I didn't understand is that this code with the string have worked for the development board but don't work for my custom board. This is strange.

Comment: Hi Bodo, update. As you said in the project settings the printf/sprintf stands off for floats. I just set it on and now it works. Thank you so much for everything!!!

Comment: You could consider sending integer values and doing the float calculation in your python code.

Comment: Hi Bodo, small question. What is the need of the if statement? Was this to test why I was gettting the empty spaces. Can I also directly say: uint16_t bytes = sizeof(values) - 1;

Comment: Read the [documentation of `snprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf), especially about the return value. If you would always use `uint16_t bytes = sizeof(values) - 1;` you would write the contents of the whole array, not only the part that has been filled by `snprintf`. This will send garbage after the data which may include parts of previous values if these needed a longer string.